# Can I answer a question after it has got an accepted answer or a better answer?

Tags: discussion, answers

I would like to know whether I can answer a question under these circumstances:

1. The question has an accepted answer. But my answer isn't as good as it is. It is a different approach and can be used in similar situation or help in Vim scripting.
2. The question has an answer better than what I am going to write. Example: question is to do an action, answer has 8 keystrokes used. My answer has 15 keystrokes.

The question was asked long ago in either case. Can I answer if my answer gives solution to the question?

Answer (score 11):

Yes to both 1 and 2. More specifically:

1. If your answer is an *entirely different way* of doing things then by all means *add it*. That it already has an "accepted answer" is of no importance, your answer will still be useful to future readers. And if your answer is better, the OP can move the accepted mark to your answer!
2. Less keystrokes do not make for better answers. This is not VimGolf. In my daily workflow I often use "suboptimal" ways of doing things as I find them either easier to remember or less error-prone than the "optimal" way of doing things.

I've often answered questions from months or sometimes even *years* ago simply because I found a new/better way of doing things.

Answer (score 9):

## Of course.

Variety is the spice of life. :)

And, IMO, sometimes a longer method is clearer and easier to remember than a golfed one. Who knows, maybe a third user might combine your solution and the existing one and obtain yet another way.

In general, you shouldn't hesitate to post an alternative answer if either of the following is true:

- your answer is significantly different from existing ones
- you explain things better than existing answers